# Use same control ID in different Panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms, panel

How can I get separate `NamingContainer`s for different `asp:Panel` server controls?

In the following .aspx markup, I see that:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Case1" CssClass="caseEvaluationContainer">
     <asp:Label ID="NamingContainer1" Text=<%# Case1.NamingContainer.UniqueID %> Runat="server"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="UniqueID1" Text="<%# Case1.UniqueID %>" Runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>


<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Case4" CssClass="caseEvaluationContainer">
     <asp:Label ID="NamingContainer4" Text=<%# Case1.NamingContainer.UniqueID %> runat="server"></asp:Label>
     <br />
     <asp:Label ID="UniqueID4" Text="<%# Case1.UniqueID %>" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

The `UniqueID`s are shown to be different, but ***not*** the `NamingContainer`s.

How can I get something like the following to work (I need controls with the same ID's on the page ***without*** using a separate databinding containers like `asp:Repeater` or `asp:FormView`.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="TestPanel1">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SameControlID"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="TestPanel2">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="SameControlID"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Why do you want them to have the same ID? I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It does not make sense of same control with multiple id , it can create problem in javascript also.

Comment: You could probably use `ContentPlaceHolder` and wrap your panels, or their content, into it. But, as everyone else said, this is a pretty strange scenario. What do you need this for?

Comment: @Devesh, @mason, @Andrei I had to copy/paste the markup in the panels 4x (instead of using a `UserControl` because my boss thought it would take too much time) so I ended up with ID's on the controls being the same in `asp:Panel`s 1-4.  This worked fine _while_ the panels were contained in separate `asp:Repeater`s...obviously this does _not_ work if the markup is contained in _only_ `asp:Panel`s.  Renaming them is far too complex, even for a good `RegEx`pert so I'll try to use `ContentPlaceHolder`, but this _really_ should have been done as a `UserControl` as @SurfThru suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the same control ID on a Page. Even if these were just HTML DIVs with the same ID you would have a collision.

If you want to handle the code in one manner in the code behind make the contents of your panels into one user control. Then you can drop that one user control in each panel. In that way you can have one set of code to manage the control.

[Code sample download.](http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/2012/11/14/Dynamically-Adding-User-Controls-to-an-ASPX-page)

Answer (score 2):

> I need controls with the same ID's on the page

You cannot. It violates the HTML rule.

[ID must be document-wide unique.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way that you can achieve by having a same class name of the control with different id like this

```
             <input type="text" id="id1" class="same" />
             <input type="text" id="id2" class="same" />
```